# How to hard populate a column using an equation

Tags: sql, metabase

I want to make a column where row 1 is `A` and every row afterwards is growing exponentially `A(1.20)^x` where `x` is time.

Using this column compare it with an already existing column in my DB.

EDIT:

Ex goal:

| Date | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 120 |
| 3 | 164 |
| 4 | 196.8 |

I dont know where to begin.

Comment: Please specify your actual DBMS in a separate tag in your question, since different DBMSses provide different technical features. Also please provide some sample data and your own attempts so far, so that it will be easier to supply you with tips and/or solutions.

Comment: `time` is not reasonable as an exponent.  Integers or real numbers (for non-negative values) are reasonable.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.